# How to iterate a Redis sorted set(ZADD/ ZRANGEBYSCORE) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, redis

The data I am working with requires me to cache and manipulate it in Redis, which will store the Unix time in an ordered list that I need to iterate over later. But I could not find that much information on how to iterate over a Redis sorted set (in this case `ZRANGEBYSCORE`). So I wanted some advice on how it should be done. The score used in data is in milliseconds. I wrote down the pseudo-code but if anyone knows a better way, please let me know. Below is some of the logic I have so far in Node.js.

```
redis.ZADD(`my-sorted-set`, Date.now() + 10*60*1000, 'member1');
redis.ZADD(`my-sorted-set`, Date.now() + 20*60*1000, 'member2');
redis.ZADD(`my-sorted-set`, Date.now() + 30*60*1000, 'member3');
Here is the pseudo code on what kind of logic I want to implement...
redis.ZRANGEBYSCORE(`my-sorted-set`, 0,Date.now()+ 100*60*1000,'withscores',function(err,result){
  //  iterate through members.... like an array 
  // remove oldest member 
  // add newest member
});
```

Comment: Do you already have a list of timestamps that needs to be in an ordered way or the timestamps will be inserted in redis as and when event occurs? If the timestamps are event based, you can use a simple list, because event time is anyway going to be in ascending order.

Comment: No there is no prior list of timestamps. They are added directly to Redis by using Date.now()

Answer (score 2):

If the timestamps are generated using the script, you don't really need to worry about maintaining the order of the timestamps since they are going to be generated in ascending order, and so you can use a list to store the generated timestamps.

Everytime a timestamp is generated, append it in the redis list using 'RPUSH' command, and you can fetch that list from redis using the 'LRANGE' command.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

current_ts = Date.now();
client.rpush('DEMO_LIST', current_ts);

current_ts = Date.now();
client.rpush('DEMO_LIST', current_ts);

current_ts = Date.now();
client.rpush('DEMO_LIST', current_ts);

client.lrange("DEMO_LIST", 0, -1, function(err, redis_list) {
  console.log(redis_list);
});
```

Output:

```
[ '1609513808868',
  '1609513869541',
  '1609566462802' ]
```

The generated timestamp (which is ever increasing) gets appended to the list and the list has timestamps in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ankit. The thing is I am getting my data from existing data in redis Cache using redis.set and redis.get  logic looks like this: cache.get(`my-sorted-set`, (err, value) => {
          if (err) return err;
          if (!value) {
              cache.set(`my-sorted-set`, Date.now() + 60*60*1000);
              cache.PEXPIREAT(`my-sorted-set`, Date.now() + 60*60*1000);
          }
      });

Comment: Can you iterate in the list made with 'RPUSH'  and if so how?